# Pandas dataframe: change duplicated rows so the first duplicates are in consecutive order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a ton of rows and columns. The following dataframe is just a simplified version of it.

```
dct = {'day': ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
       'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 
              '6', '7', '8', '9']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

```
    day id
0   Mon  1
1   Tue  2
2   Wed  3
3   Wed  4
4  Thur  5
5   Fri  6
6   Fri  7
7   Sat  8
8   Sun  9
```

I want to change the ids to match the duplicated days (in this scenario) but still be consecutive.

```
    day id
0   Mon  1
1   Tue  2
2   Wed  3
3   Wed  3
4  Thur  4
5   Fri  5
6   Fri  5
7   Sat  6
8   Sun  7
```

So far i managed to change the ids but they are not consecutive and i'm kinda stuck right now.

```
m = df['day'].duplicated()
df['id'] = df['id'].mask(m).ffill()
```

```
    day id
0   Mon  1
1   Tue  2
2   Wed  3
3   Wed  3
4  Thur  5
5   Fri  6
6   Fri  6
7   Sat  8
8   Sun  9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) values:

```
# ensure using numeric dtype
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(int)

# subtract duplicated cumsum
df['id'] -= df['day'].duplicated().cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    day  id
0   Mon   1
1   Tue   2
2   Wed   3
3   Wed   3
4  Thur   4
5   Fri   5
6   Fri   5
7   Sat   6
8   Sun   7
```

Intermediates:

```
    day  id  duplicated  cumsum  id-cumsum
0   Mon   1       False       0          1
1   Tue   2       False       0          2
2   Wed   3       False       0          3
3   Wed   4        True       1          3
4  Thur   5       False       1          4
5   Fri   6       False       1          5
6   Fri   7        True       2          5
7   Sat   8       False       2          6
8   Sun   9       False       2          7
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much. It works and i get it. A follow up question. What if the duplicated rows were not in order? Like this: Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Wed, Fri

Comment: @tanzwood it depends which output you expect, you might want to sort temporarily on the desired order. Feel free to [ask a follow up question](/questions/ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the previous `day` with the current `day`, and every time it changes, increment a count (using [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)):

```py
df['id'] = (df['day'] != df['day'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    day  id
0   Mon   1
1   Tue   2
2   Wed   3
3   Wed   3
4  Thur   4
5   Fri   5
6   Fri   5
7   Sat   6
8   Sun   7
```